# Blocking Salesforce Inspector - or other browser extension

Tags: chrome, browser, loginflow, transaction-security-policy

I love SF Inspector due to its ease of use and ability to browse SF objects, and I hate SF Inspector for the same reason.

I would like to find a way to control the user of browser extensions - but from within Salesforce versus at the local machine level.

I did some quick research and found that I could build a login flow to recognize the browser that someone is using ( https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2018/12/14/implement-login-securities-with-flows-restrict-login-browser/ ) or use a Transaction Security Policy.

But... how to get at if a browser extension is enabled?

I found this... https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/

but am not sure this could be accessed via a SF Login Flow.

Thoughts?

Comment: The inspector can only do what the user can do, so why does it matter if it is done through a plugin, laboriously through the UI or via a REST API?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Because with SF Inspector, a user can bypass Transaction Security Policies that limit the number of records that could be exported.  We can control who uses, DL, Workbench, Dev Console... but extensions are a risk.

Comment: _Because with SF Inspector, a user can bypass Transaction Security Policies that limit the number of records that could be exported_ : not quite. Just because the extension uses its own simple mechanism for querying rather than, say, bulk or report API does not mean it cannot be stopped. Preventing a user from downloading a lot of records via Inspector is doable. It requires a custom policy in Apex and a bit of ingenuity in terms of keeping track of what actions the user has performed but it can be done.

Comment: Hmmm.... I didnt think about going after the APIEvent.  I will check that out. Thanks for the idea @identigral

Comment: The APIEvent table is great !